# Problematic slashes at my URLs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've got a web page with URLs like http://www.domain.com/section.whatever.php. Problem is, whenever an URL like http://www.domain.com/section.whatever.php/something, the page still works but the slash completely destroys the design of the web, I suppose it makes the browser think all the static assets like images and CSS are at the wrong directory level.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have any `mod_rewrite` code yourself? Have you looked at the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to update all your links to static resources so that they are absolute (from the root of the domain). For example: `/stylesheets/screen.css`

Comment: The question is not abandoned, is just that I'm waiting a few days to see if someone comes up with something more imaginative as I hoped there was some magical mod_rewrite regex solution for the slashes problem. Don't get me wrong, yours is a solution perfectly valid that I didn't think of, is just that I expected something more glamorous. :D

Comment: In fact I've been checking some CMS like Wordpress and this seems to be their solution to the problem.